# Rails Link Multiple One Model to Multiple Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I'm writing a basic checkers game in ruby on rails.

So I have a Player model and a Game model. Each Game will have two players. And each players can have many games (because they can play multiple games).

What's the most effective way to store which two users belong to a Game? I could make fields as like `player_one_id:integer` and `player_two_id:integer` but that feels a little hacky. And then looking up what games a player is currently in wouldn't be efficient.

What's the best way to accomplish something like this? Ideally they are cleanly stored and I can easily check to see what game a player is currently in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two player columns as you suggest (i.e. `player_one_id` and `player_two_id`) and set model relationships like this:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player_one, class: "Player"
  belongs_to :player_two, class: "Player"
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
end
```

I don't think it is *hacky* at all, since you will always have two players for each game.

As for *looking up what games a player is currently in*, you could do it like this:

```
Game.where("player_one_id = ? OR player_two_id = ?", player_id, player_id)
```

Comment: This does seem pretty smooth! I'll give er a go! Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

You have a "player_one" table...

```
 player_one
 -----------
 (PK) player_one_id
 EngineerName
```

And a "player_two" table...

```
 player_two
 ---------
 (PK) player_two_id
 player_name
```

You now add a link table called "Games" (or similar) which references the Ids of both the `player_one` and `player_two`...

```
 Games
 ------------------
 (PK) GameId
 (FK) player_one_id
 (FK) player_two_id
```

So that way, you keep all the Player One Details and the Player Two details separately, and link them using ONLY the Ids... the link table would look something like this...

```
  player_one | player_two
 ------------+----------
      1      |    1
      1      |    2
      1      |    3
      2      |    1
      2      |    2
      2      |    3
```

This is best practice and it gives you the most opportunity for expansion.